# Select * faster than select column

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
WITH Categories (child_oid, Level) AS ( 
   SELECT h.child_oid, 
          0 AS Level 
     FROM Memx_productcatalog.dbo.ME_CatalogHierarchy AS h 
     JOIN dbo.[ME_CatalogProducts] c on h.oid = c.oid 
    WHERE c.CategoryName = 'Root' 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT h.child_oid, 
          Level + 1 
     FROM dbo.ME_CatalogHierarchy AS h 
     JOIN Categories AS p ON p.child_oid = h.oid ) --End CTE Recursive
SELECT p.oid --problem here
  FROM dbo.ME_CatalogProducts as p
 WHERE p.oid IN (SELECT child_oid 
                   FROM Categories)
```

I'm writing a recursive CTE SQL statement to pull items from a tree. The query works fine. When I select a specific column(s) the query executes in ~300ms.  However when I use `select *` or `p.*`, the query executes under 100ms.  This is the exact opposite of what I would expect. I have checked indexes, statistics, and both queries seem to generate the same execution plan. I'm stumped on this one.

**Update**

I've been running this query all day with consistent results. I've attempted to disable caching by using OPTION (RECOMPILE). I've just been using the "Wait time on server replies" in sql manager to measure the query execution (is that bad?) Here is what happens when I use SET STATISTICS TIME ON.

p.oid =>   SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 203 ms,  elapsed time = 270 ms.
"Wait time" = 195ms

p.* =>   SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 469 ms,  elapsed time = 1015 ms.
"Wait time" = 21ms

I have the other stats if they are needed. Is the client wait time time the wrong way to measure these things?

Comment: How many tests have you done? Have you tried reversing the order of the tests (in case caching is playing a part)? What does `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and  `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` say for both?

Comment: Perhaps I have a flawed understanding, but I would expect `*` to be faster. After all, the db will not need to perform any projection.

Comment: @syrion: You don't think that limiting the data returned would be faster?

Comment: No, because I would expect the database to return all of the columns and then eliminate the ones that aren't needed, thus adding an extra step to the computation of the set.

Comment: Syrion you are wrong, very wrong. google it and you will see. This is why this question is interesting, if its correct. Iam waiting for data from @Martin 's comment

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm basing my comment on a conceptual model provided by a professor, so.

Comment: @syrion Who is your professor? Not that I'm surprised (unfortunately).

Comment: In standard SQL, everything I've read says selecting columns is faster than using wild cards.  So I understand your confusion.

However, you are using CTE (Common Table Expressions).  I'm going to guess when a wild card is used, it's faster for CTE to clone the entire table structure rather than build one from scratch.

Comment: @syrion can you be a bit more specific? :)

Comment: @stefan why is syrion wrong? * should be faster it doesn't have to project anything, just return the entire matrix, however if you're matrix is really massive then specific tables may be faster.

Comment: @Saad because of reality. @Danielg so the specific query is Twice as fast CPU time wise than the * one...

Comment: @stefan It would appear so. I guess I won't be trusting the sql manager again.

Comment: @stefan but that still depends on n, it's not clear cut answer.

Comment: @Saad it's the best iam willing to give you. Just google and you shall see, its a truth everyone who doesn't do academic rdbms knows about. Prety much i would say forget all you learnt at uni, Uni sql-folks are generally clueless (been there done that).

Comment: @stefan if Martin wants to submit his comment as an answer I would accept that. Otherwise I'll just close it and take the hit.

Comment: @Richard cool, didnt know. Still good to have a documented answer tho :)

Comment: Could you provide a link to an explanation of why my conception is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827726/sql-server-management-studio-client-statistics-wait-time-on-server-replies/1828400#1828400)

'Wait time on server replies' is the time between the last request packet left the client and the very first response packet returned from the server.

On my machine it seems that it waits until it has somewhere around 4000 bytes to return before sending the first packet from the test below.

When `*` is selected fewer rows need to be processed to fill this buffer.

```
SELECT 'A'
WAITFOR delay '00:00:02'
```

Gives

```
  TDS packets sent from client        1
  TDS packets received from server    1
  Bytes sent from client              180        
  Bytes received from server          610    
  Client processing time              8    
  Total execution time                2008    
  Wait time on server replies         2000
```

And

```
SELECT REPLICATE('A',4000)
WAITFOR delay '00:00:02'
```

Gives

```
  Number of server roundtrips         1
  TDS packets sent from client        1
  TDS packets received from server    2
  Bytes sent from client              222
  Bytes received from server          4619
  Client processing time              1885
  Total execution time                1914
  Wait time on server replies         29
```

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that using the MS SQL manager to measure execution times is very unreliable. 
Thanks to Martin using SET STATISTICS TIME ON gave me more accurate results.

Doing SELECT * is actually much slower than doing a column select when measured correctly